# Reading in multiple png files in order to create a new plot with grid.arrange

Tags: r

Let's say that I just created 4 histograms in ggplot2. After finishing, I realized that I should have used grid.arrange to combine some of the plots into a single graphics device. There is the png and jpeg packages in CRAN, both of which can be used to overlay graphics on a plot. Besides rerunning the visualizations again, are there packages in R that can be used to import multiple png files and then used to arrange a graphics device with each of them on it?

Here's some sample code, though the visualization are all the same.

```
df = data.frame(one=c(1,3,5,6,7,3,4,5,2,5,3,1,2))
df

library(ggplot2)
p1 = qplot(one, data=df, geom="histogram")
p2 = qplot(one, data=df, geom="histogram")
p3 = qplot(one, data=df, geom="histogram")
p4 = qplot(one, data=df, geom="histogram")

png("my_viz1.png")
p1
dev.off()

png("my_viz2.png")
p2
dev.off()

png("my_viz3.png")
p3
dev.off()

png("my_viz4.png")
p4
dev.off()
```

Comment: Failing to use print(plot_obj) is a common source of confused R users. (And please do read the rest of the R-FAQ where the reason is explained in more detail.) I also see no description of what sort of output is desired. The png device will not produce multiple pages but the pdf device will.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
rl = lapply(sprintf("my_viz%i.png", 1:4), png::readPNG)
gl = lapply(rl, grid::rasterGrob)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs=gl)
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would have gone to some length to avoid reimporting the saved graphics, and I would have rerun the visualisations again, if at all possible, in order to have code that is guaranteed to produce the same results next time. It is always a risk to rely on that external files are not accidentally deleted or modified.

However, sometimes you need a really quick hack, and if that is your situation right now, try this:

```
library("png")
library("raster")
plot(0:2, 0:2, type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
rasterImage(readPNG(source="my_viz1.png"), 0, 1, 1, 2)
rasterImage(readPNG(source="my_viz2.png"), 1, 1, 2, 2)
rasterImage(readPNG(source="my_viz3.png"), 0, 0, 1, 1)
rasterImage(readPNG(source="my_viz4.png"), 1, 0, 2, 1)
```