# How can I make multipanel plots of several png files in R?

Tags: r

I want to plot these png files side-by-side (from http://www.atmos.uw.edu/~akchen0/CERES_Project/ ) - arranged in a 2x1 or a 3x1 panel. I've already installed readPNG.

Comment: So these are plots made by someone else, and you just want to combine them into one image?

Comment: Oh - these are my own plots. And yes I want to combine them into one image.

Comment: Then i would combine them before you turn them into PNG files. What commands are you using to generate them?

Comment: Combining them into subplots before turning into PNG files is turning into a nightmare, and I'm not sure if anyone has solved the problem. See http://qr.ae/K79oi

Comment: Oh, so you're not making the plots in R. There many ways in R to put multiple plots into the same image, but doing that with existing PNGs is less common.

Comment: Non-R solutions come to mind faster: [GIMP](http://gimp.org) and [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org) (perhaps in "montage" mode) being the first two. I like R, but it doesn't make cole slaw like Mom used to make, so why force it? (If you're trying to automate it, I'd likely still use imagemagick with an interpreted language like bash or python. It can be done in R but seems it bit unnecessary.)

Answer (score 2):

There is already a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107126/reading-in-multiple-png-files-in-order-to-create-a-new-plot-with-grid-arrange) on this subject, so I will repeat this with a slight modification:

Assume your plots are `p1.png`, `p2.png`...

```
rl <- lapply(list("p1.png", "p2.png"), png::readPNG)
gl <- lapply(rl, grid::rasterGrob)
do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, gl)
```

Giving:[image]

This is rather slow on my device and not terribly pretty. You may want to look at e.g. `?grid::pushViewport` to gain more control over plotting and positioning. As the comments suggest, `R` may not be the ideal tool for this. If on Windows, something as simple as Paint may suffice and would prob. be faster.